# See if JSON data is in file, if not, check the next file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How would one go about checking if JSON data is in one file, if it's not in that file, check another file, for example

Say this is "test.json"

```json
{
"test":"test"
}
```

and say this is "base.json"

```json
{
"base":"base"
}
```

And say that I have a variable in my program called `EnabledJSONFiles`, and it looks something like this (Python): `EnabledJSONFiles=['test.json', 'base.json']`. And the program has a user prompt to search for something, and say the user searches for "base", the current implementation that I have uses the `for i in range(len(EnabledJSONFiles))`, but when it doesn't find it in the first json file, it just crashes out. So how would one go about fixing that so that it checks the next file?

Additionally, it also produces this error

```
  File "/home/white/projects/pyjson.py", line 10, in handler
    for value in entry[argument]:
KeyError: 'test'
```

Comment: 1. Read the error message and try to understand it. 2. Use an IDE that provides a debugger. Use the debugger.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question a) without the error message and b) without a [mre]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We can only tell you what is wrong with code that you actually show to us. Also, "it just crashes out" is not helpful - you should never expect anyone else to be able to tell anything useful with that description, and you should *never be satisfied to yourself* understanding the problem that way. Errors produce long error messages for a *reason*; they are *useful* and your instinct should be to try to *read and understand* them.

Answer (score 1):

For your loop it seems like you are using the wrong sort of iteration, the `range()` function returns the index so when you are trying to open your files it will try to open  a file called `0` then a file called `1` etc (which don't exist). Since you aren't using any index operations I would just use the native iteration syntax.

Something like this:

```py
import json

for json_file in EnabledJSONFiles:
    with open(json_file, "r") as open_file:
        content = json.load(open_file)
        ... # Check for values in file and break if it's found
```

if you just want to print the correct file then you can make this into a function such as:

```py
import json

def find_value_in_files(EnabledJSONFiles:list, value:str) -> str:
    for json_file in EnabledJSONFiles:
        with open(json_file, "r") as open_file:
            
            content = json.load(open_file)# Assuming the content is laid out exactly as it is in your example this will be a dictionary
            if content.get(value, False): # look for value and 
                return json_file
    return "" # Return an empty string if no file is found with the value
```

This would then be invoked using:

```py
EnabledJSONFiles=['test.json', 'base.json']

print(find_value_in_files(EnabledJSONFiles, "base")) # Prints base.json
```

### Notes on this approach

#### File paths

I also noticed your `EnabledJSONFiles` variable is using relative paths, make sure when writing this list the files actually go to the right paths, and that those files exist. [os.path.isfile()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-isfile-method/#:%7E:text=isfile()%20method%20in%20Python,existing%20regular%20file%20or%20not.&text=Parameter%3A,representing%20a%20file%20system%20path.&text=This%20method%20returns%20True%20if,regular%20file%2C%20otherwise%20returns%20False.) can tell you if the files exist before you try to open them and you can choose what to do at that point based on your use case.

#### JSON format

When JSON files are read they can be read into multiple formats. If the files are laid out **exactly** how you wrote in your example, then this suggestion will work, if they are in a different schema, then it won't. For example if the value is in an object inside an object. Like this:

```json
{
    "test": {
        "value": "value"
    }
}
```

Comment: `for` is not the wrong choice. You use `for` as well. Using `range` is also ok, as long as used like `EnabledJSONFiles[i]`. This answer is based on assumptions

Comment: @ThomasWeller true, but almost always, you don't actually want `for i in range(...)`

Comment: @ThomasWeller the OP mentioned it fails on the first pass, this means the loop is unlikely to be using the syntax you suggested and is likely passing the index directly into the ```open()``` call. The syntax you are suggesting would be fine, but there is no reason not to use the syntax presented since it is much more expressive of the intent of the loop.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I am using it in that way, I probably should've mentioned that

Comment: @Kimitzuni I would recommend avoiding doing those C style loops in situations where you don't intend to use the index for any operations (like looking at the next element, or previous, or updating the list at a given index). Several reasons for this, the first being it's easier to debug (you can just print the variable instead of needing to print the list value at the index), and the second being it's natively faster in python to do it using the syntax I suggested. If you look up "loop like a native" by Ned Batchelder there's a good pycon talk on this topic.

Comment: @Kimitzuni I also added a note to the end of my answer that might be useful. Make sure the files exist before trying to open them.